# SSIS - Unable to infer the XSD from the XML file SSIS. The XML contains multiple namespaces

Tags: xml, sharepoint, ssis, ado, xml-namespaces

**Context:** I have an XML file that I'm having trouble loading to SSIS because I keep raising the multiple namespaces error. `Unable to infer the XSD from the XML file. The XML contains multiple namespaces.`
The data in the file came from one of our Sharepoint API endpoints. Here is a snippet of the top of the XML file below.

I'm not an expert in XML - I don't understand why SSIS thinks there's multiple namespaces when it looks like there's only one `xmlns=""` that I see: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed 
xml:base="https://tlc.sharepoint.us/sites/tlc_PWA/_api/PD/" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
```

**Question:** From the other SO posts deleting or moving around this ns seemed to solve the issue for others but not for me. Can someone please help me resolve this issue so I can generate the XSD? I suspect some clashing formats may be confusing SSIS, not sure.

Comment: The provided XML contains three namespaces: one default, and two named namespaces. The best way to handle your scenario is to use XML Task, operation Tranformation to simplify XML into digestible for SSIS format.

Comment: Can you be anymore descriptive to unpack what "transformstion to simplify" means?

Comment: Please edit your question, and add (1) a minimal XML sample, and (2) a desired output to load into a db table.